# How can we concurrently run two different functions as different task in intel TBB?

Tags: c++, intel

Suppose i have two functions fun1() and fun2(). i want to run both of them concurrently on intel Threading building block. As in openmp i can use #pragma omp sections to run two differnt functions simultanously. How can we do the same using intel TBB?

Comment: Use parallel_invoke() in TBB

Answer (score 0):

parallel_invoke is a good way to accomplish this for most uses, and uses the highest-level API TBB provides for this purpose. There are other ways to do this in TBB, using lower-level APIs, that might be useful for you. The next lower-level API way to accomplish this is to create a new task_group. Going further, the lowest-level API in TBB allows you to create your own task trees, which can create arbitrary parallelism patterns. If you are going that far, the key insight you need is that **you can create more than one root task** at a time. That is not obvious in some of the documentation, but once you know it, you will likely be able to create any parallelism pattern you can imagine.

The article [Optimizing Game Architectures with Intel® Threading Building Blocks](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/optimizing-game-architectures-with-intel-threading-building-blocks) shows examples of using this lowest-level API to achieve the purpose you describe, as well as several others you may find useful.